# Play Framework add client side dependencies

Tags: javascript, playframework, sbt

I'm using the Play Framework 2.5 to built a web application. I've been using WebJars to download client side dependencies.

`libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.webjars" % "amcharts" % "3.15.0",
  ....`

But I have a lot of WebJars that are out-dated. How can I add a dependency on the GitHub repo instead? Can play/sbt download a tag and automatically place it in the asset folder? I can also place these dependencies in the public folder but that would get messy quickly.

Comment: I'm confused about what you try to achieve. Do you want to use a GitHub repo directly? You could just download the version you want and include it in your project manually. You don't have to use webjars.org. It's just a helper that gets the library for you.

Comment: I can do that but I lose the ability to quickly clean and upgrade my project.

Comment: Can't you just upgrade the webjar dependency?

Comment: @marcospereira I have to create them myself in order to do that. Which is possible but still a a lot of work.